# how to sort array of objects in javascript (any property)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort array of object using this link 
[Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

[Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

and but when I try to sort  it is not giving the expected result here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/36wp6b98/

Expected out put is this

```
[
    {
        Name: "1009834",
        Account__r: "Ad Imperial Bank",
        PO__c: "PO9957",
        Dispute__c: "-",
        Amount__c: "8182.62",
        Expected_Payment_Date__c: "Tue May 05 2015",
        Disputed_Amount__c: "0.00",
        Promised_Amount__c: "9006.80",
        Promise_Date__c: "Wed Jul 02 2014",
        Balance__c: "8182.62",
        Close_Date__c: "-",
        id: "a0RK0000002l366MAA"
    },
    {
        Name: "1009092",
        Account__r: "Canadian Imperial Bank",
        PO__c: "PO9215",
        Dispute__c: "-",
        Amount__c: "9370.98",
        Expected_Payment_Date__c: "Fri Jul 31 2015",
        Disputed_Amount__c: "0.00",
        Promised_Amount__c: "8695.90",
        Promise_Date__c: "Thu Mar 06 2014",
        Balance__c: "9370.98",
        Close_Date__c: "-",
        id: "a0RK0000002l365MAA"
    },
    {
        Name: "1008082",
        Account__r: "pacd Imperial Bank",
        PO__c: "PO8205",
        Dispute__c: "-",
        Amount__c: "4696.52",
        Expected_Payment_Date__c: "Tue May 05 2015",
        Disputed_Amount__c: "0.00",
        Promised_Amount__c: "0.00",
        Promise_Date__c: "-",
        Balance__c: "4696.52",
        Close_Date__c: "-",
        id: "a0RK0000002l364MAA"
    }

]
```

Code

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.last_nom < b.last_nom)
    return -1;
  if (a.last_nom > b.last_nom)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
var b=obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.Account__r - b.Account__r;
})
console.log(b)
```

Comment: why are you not using the compare function after making it ?

Comment: Many duplicate answers for how to sort an array of objects by a property.

Comment: I used that function but it s not returning anything ?

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter could you please give fiddle

Comment: Please change my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/36wp6b98/

Comment: got it ..!! I will update you

Comment: @Shruti https://jsfiddle.net/36wp6b98/1/ Have a nice day!